# ErrorException (E_ERROR) Use of undefined constant yonetim - assumed 'yonetim' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Tags: php, laravel-5

ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Use of undefined constant yonetim - assumed 'yonetim' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View: /srv/http/blog/resources/views/admin/template.blade.php) (View: /srv/http/blog/resources/views/admin/template.blade.php)
Previous exceptions

> Use of undefined constant yonetim - assumed 'yonetim' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View: /srv/http/blog/resources/views/admin/template.blade.php) (0)
>   Use of undefined constant yonetim - assumed 'yonetim' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (0)

php

```
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="{{ route(yonetim.index) }}"><i class="icon icon-home"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a> </li>
    <li class=""><a href="{{ route(ayarlar.index) }}"><i class="icon icon-home"></i> <span>Ayarlar</span></a> </li>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: You need quotes around your route, inside the parenthesis

Comment: and if you try this: `route('yonetim.index')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `<li>` with this as you are missing quotes:

```
<li class="active"><a href="{{ route('yonetim.index') }}"><i class="icon icon-home"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a> </li>
<li class=""><a href="{{ route('ayarlar.index') }}"><i class="icon icon-home"></i> <span>Ayarlar</span></a> </li>
```

Can also try:

Example route for below: `Route::get('/home/index', 'HomeController@index');`

```
<li class="active"><a href="{{ '/home/index' }}"><i class="icon icon-home"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a> </li>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just replace your code with this,

```
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="{{ 'route(yonetim.index)' }}"><i class="icon icon-home"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a> </li>
    <li class=""><a href="{{ 'route(ayarlar.index)' }}"><i class="icon icon-home"></i> <span>Ayarlar</span></a> </li>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. If you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).